# Recovering a locked iPod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

My kid has an iPod touch that has locked from too many attempts to enter the passcode for 22 million seconds. He did this before and I connected to iTunes and it successfully unlocked it.
However, I have subsequently upgraded the computer that iTunes was on, and, although the original hard disk is readable, I can't boot it, and can't seem to repair it.
Can I install iTunes on the new computer and copy over some key files or something like that from the original iTunes install to get this device unlocked?

Comment: Have you thought about dropping by one of the Apple stores?  They do a lot of this kind of stuff free at their Genius bars.

Comment: Is this the 1st generation? I've seen some of these that say the equivalent of 40 years in minutes. It might be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try restoring the iPod touch? If you enter DFU mode (described below) and click Restore, you'll get the iPod back up and running.

**To enter DFU mode...**

- Press and hold the Home and Power buttons until the device turns off.
- When it does, hold Power for three seconds.
- The device should turn on. Now hold the Home and Power buttons (DON'T LET GO OF Power) for ten seconds. The device should turn off - that's fine.
- Let go of Power -- keep holding Home until you hear your PC recognise the device.

The iPod touch should subsequently be available in iTunes as if it were in recovery mode; you should now be able to restore the device.